# Google Image Meta

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to obtain media meta such as created at time stamp (Google called that property 'time').
For images (eg jpg) this is straight forward, Google reads the exif data.
This does not seem to be true for video (mp4).
This info seems to be somewhere as when looking at the link there is info as to when it was taken:

[image]

However the info provided by the api does not seem to provide this.

[image]

I am obviously missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation for `Files`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), the specific field for a video is the `videoMediaMetadata`, with the following subfields:

- `videoMediaMetadata.width` which represents the width of the video in pixels;
- `videoMediaMetadata.height` which represents the height of the video in pixels;
- `videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis` which represents the the duration of the video in milliseconds.

However, it is important to note the following:

> The `videoMediaMetadata` represents the aditional metadata about video media and *this may not be available immediately upon upload*.

Moreover, if you want to retrieve the `videoMediaMetadata` field specifically, you should mention it in the request your making.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files).

Comment: thanks, do you have more info. I have shown my results in the question with videoMediaMetadata so unsure why you a explaining this again. Also the clip is a 1 second test, taken a while ago, while the meta was queried sometime after that and not shown.

Comment: These are the only available fields for a file of type video.